# Implement JWT authentication in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I want to implement JWT authentication with Spring Boot based on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/spring-boot-security-jwt-hello-world-example-b479e457664c).

Endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/authorize")
public String login(@Valid @RequestBody AuthenticationDTO resetDTO) {
    return userRestService.authorize(resetDTO.getName(), resetDTO.getPassword());
}

public String authorize(String username, String password) {
    try {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));

        Optional<Users> user = userService.findByLogin(username);
        if(!user.isPresent()){
            throw new EngineException(ErrorDetail.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return jwtTokenProvider.createToken(username, Collections.singletonList(user.get().getRole()));
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        throw new EngineException(ErrorDetail.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Full  code: [Github](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/d87c10f6181929cfa4e64f02ddb729d44ed01d62/src/main/java/org/engine/service/UserRestService.java#L39)

When I make a POST request to authenticate user:

```
{
    "name": "admin",
    "password": "qwerty"
}
```

I get this [full log](https://pastebin.com/qPg1yexB)

I don't see into the log any SQL query ti get the credentials from the database. Looks like `authenticationManager.authenticate` is not making authentication.

Do you know what might cause this problem and how to fix this?

Comment: you don't have to write your own implementation, spring-security supports Jwt authentication

Comment: ok, what should be the endpoint and how to make a authentication?

Comment: you can customize the authentication endpoint to your needs, there is plenty of samples online.

Comment: @PeterPenzov, Is the authentication succeeding? If not, I would suggest you to debug the app, set a breakpoint and log an statement at the _UserDetailsHandler_ and _UsersServiceImpl_. This is just to make sure they are being invoked while the authentication happens. Also check for cache in hibernate which may prevent second trips to the DB. Finally. you can also make sure the log level is the correct one to see what you are expecting. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem